# Chain MySQL statements under JBoss

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jboss, jndi

EDIT: the linked answer doesn't use `LAST_INSERT_ID`, still looking for answer.

I'm using JBoss and getting connections via DataSource (JNDI).

How can I chain and execute multiple SQL statements in one go, where the second statement depends on the output of the first (`LAST_INSERT_ID()`)

```
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO product(name) VALUES(?); INSERT INTO brand_product(brand_id, product_id) VALUES(?, LAST_INSERT_ID())", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
preparedStatement.setInt(2, brandId);

if(preparedStatement.executeUpdate() != 0) {
    try (ResultSet generatedKeys = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
        if(generatedKeys.next()) {
            product = new Product(generatedKeys.getInt(1), name);
        }
    }
};
```

Please note: I've generated keys in use as well, the second table is not generating any keys since it's a join table.

Comment: it's not duplicate, my question uses `LAST_INSERT_ID`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL ConnectorJ with multiple SQL statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219552/mysql-connectorj-with-multiple-sql-statements)

Comment: @GordThompson the link within the answer is broken, can you please link the page here, I'm using JBOSS, and connecting via DATA source, JNDI

Comment: [This](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) is a current link. (I also updated the other answer.)

Comment: well how this works with Jboss, I'm using DataSource, not direct connections

Comment: If you are using a `MysqlDataSource` object then I would think it should be possible for you to use `.setAllowMultiQueries(true)`.

Comment: You should add jboss to the post. Also when you chain 2 statements and you add the Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS, it is probably provider dependent. I would think that having two statements confuses the driver you are using. What about if one of the statements does not involve generated keys?

Comment: thanks, I've clarified the question, that's the reason I put generated keys question so an answer can cover that aspect too from knowledgeable people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Configure JBoss to allow multiple Queries in admin interface. Click disable first before adding properties. (under DataSources).

   propertyName: `allowMultiQueries` property value: `true`
2. Generated keys will not have an issue since the second query doesn't have Auto increment primary keys.